# Determine programmatically if we're connecting to SharePoint Online or on-premise with CSOM API

Tags: c#, sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, office365, csom

I would like to know if there is a way to determine if we're about to connect to a SharePoint Online server or an on-premise one (as the Credentials object type differs). I'm using the CSOM API in C# with a SharePoint 2013 and a SharePoint Online server.

So far, I haven't found anything useful in the [ClientContext](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext_members.aspx) object itself so I'm thinking to just check the login that the user to see if it's login is like "DOMAIN\ACCOUNT" or "account@domain.tld" but I don't know if it's possible to have a Domain\Account login type on SharePoint Online or something else.

If it's impossible to do, I'll just ask the user to tell what type of server it is.

Comment: I don't have a way to check it now, but if I recall correctly, when you use ADFS in O365, you also use login in format `domain\username`.

Comment: hmm, I have a fresh new SharePoint online site without any modification and I want my code to be the more compatible possible. ATM I have a dropdown list that shows the login methods: Domain Account, Office Online and Guest. I change the Credential object with this information so the user can just choose "domain account" if its SP Online server use ADFS :) _(thanks again for your participation, it's awesome for me to talk with other passionate devs!)_

Answer (score 1):

There is a `MicrosoftSharePointTemaServices` header in HTTP response sent back from SharePoint. It contains version number. 2013 will return `15.0.0.xxxx` and O365 `16.0.0.xxxx` (at least now, in future they may bump the version).

You can retrieve it like this:

```
var request = WebRequest.Create("https://sharepoint.contoso.com");
try
{
    request.GetResponse(); //fails with 401
}
catch (WebException ex)
{
    var version = ex.Response.Headers["MicrosoftSharePointTeamServices"];
}
```

Comment: We also automatically retrieve the version number through the ClientContext instance (these attributes are available after the first ClientContext.ExecuteQuery method) : [screenshot](http://imgur.com/V62AZC2). More informations here: [ClientContext members](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.clientcontext_members.aspx).

Comment: But I don't like this approach. When someone will use a SharePoint 2016 on-premise, the server version will be 16.x and if I hardcoded this number to be the Online version, it will be an issue. I want my code to be as dynamic as possible. What I want here is a boolean (or an enum) that tell me if it's "on-premise" or "online". For now, I just ask the user for the server type, I don't think I've the choice :)

Comment: @HendrickxMatthias Yes, you can get the version from ClientContext, but you need to create the context first and you don't know how :) But you're right about 2016. Checking the version is only good if on prem version is 2013.

Comment: Well, you can create a ClientContext without credentials then try to ExecuteQuery. It works on my on-premise server, not on the online one (idk why), [here is what I just tried](http://pastebin.com/KdpG1qNX).

Comment: spContextOnline throw an exception and spContextOnPremise succeed to fetch its attributes. I don't think it's a reliable way btw, it may be something you can configure in your server settings. I'm pretty new to SharePoint itself, I just use its CSOM API since few months :)